# How to make comodo popup overlay other elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a comodo secure logo but on hover the popup is appearing under other page elements. My CSS is:

```
a[onmouseout="tLpB('tl_popupCL1')"] {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99999;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Page is [here](https://www.stakeholdermap.com/stakeholder-management-templates.html)

The comodo secure logo and behaviour is all fine it is just that I need the popop to appear on top. The jscript is below if needed.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">TrustLogo("https://www.stakeholdermap.com/comodo_secure_seal_113x59_transp.png", "CL1", "none");</script><a  href="https://ssl.comodo.com" id="comodoTL">SSL Certificates</a>
```

Comment: Where on the page is this link of yours?

Comment: scroll down to the bullet list. logo is immediately below the green accordion.

Comment: It looks like there is some positioning algorithm that places the box and when the box is below the logo, it gets cut off by the container. Your container has overflow hidden which I am unsure why, so if you can remove that, it should be fine

Comment: Thanks Huangism. That doesn't seem to have worked. Sometimes the popup appears on top other times it is obscured by the bootstrap panel.

Comment: Your `.eb2` div has overflow hidden

Comment: thanks that has worked. just sometimes ends up underneath the ad below, but much better thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Hunagism said in his comment, remove `overflow: hidden;` from your `.eb2` `div`. Then, to get the popup to display over the ad, in this element (`#aswift_0_anchor`):

```
<ins id="aswift_0_anchor" style="display:block;border:none;height:280px;margin:0;padding:0;position:relative;visibility:visible;width:336px;background-color:transparent"><iframe width="336" height="280" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen="true" onload="var i=this.id,s=window.google_iframe_oncopy,H=s&amp;&amp;s.handlers,h=H&amp;&amp;H[i],w=this.contentWindow,d;try{d=w.document}catch(e){}if(h&amp;&amp;d&amp;&amp;(!d.body||!d.body.firstChild)){if(h.call){setTimeout(h,0)}else if(h.match){try{h=s.upd(h,i)}catch(e){}w.location.replace(h)}}" id="aswift_0" name="aswift_0" style="left:0;position:absolute;top:0;width:336px;height:280px;"></iframe></ins>
```

add `z-index: -1;`

Comment: Thanks Anthony. Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What about it doesn't work? You're adding `z-index` of  `-1` to the element with the `id` `aswift_0_anchor`?

Comment: got it, was adding to ins style. doh. Is working thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem and I used a simpler solution by changing the z-index of the mouseover popup from `0` top `999999`. See the code below and add it next to your Comodo code snippet.

```
<style type="text/css">#tl_popupCL1 { z-index: 999999 !important }</style>
```